# Proper Protocol for Connecting to Azure SQL DB for ASP.NET Web Forms Site

Tags: asp.net, database, azure, webforms, connection-string

New to ASP.NET trying to connect to an Azure SQL DB.  I don't know exactly what to include in the connection string.  I've viewed many posts from this site but a lot of the answers have different content in the connString.

The following is my Form_Load event handler code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declare connection sting for Azure SQl DB
            string strSQLconnection = "Data Source=someValue.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True";

            //create SqlConnection object and pass strSQLconnect variable from above as parameter
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);

            //create SqlCommand object and select table EMPLOYEES from Azure DB for grid view (to test) and pass sqlConnection from above as parameter
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Employees", sqlConnection);

            //open the SQL connection
            sqlConnection.Open();

            //create SqlDataReader object to be able to read from Azure DB
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();



            gvAzureSql.DataSource = reader;

            gvAzureSql.DataBind();
        }
```

Note:  I added the gridView just for testing purposes to see if data has been binded; wont be on implemented form.

Also, Im using the address on the top left of the Azure db site; is this correct (`########.database.window.net`)

I've seen solutions advising to add connection string tag in web.config.  Do I also have to do this.  If so, may you provide the proper protocol to set this up for Azure SQL DB.  I've searched for a long time and can't find a definitive question or process of exactly what to enter in the connString.

Thanks

Comment: A simple search for `Azure SQL database connection string` led me to this on https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/: `Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;`

Comment: do I also add this to web.config?

Comment: You should if you want to change that later in without recompiling your code.

Comment: Last question I promise.  Do I replace the default connection string or simply add another one in web.config?

Comment: :) Please change the default connection string to keep things simple. Just in case you get connection failed error (because you promised to ask last question :)), make sure firewall rules are set to allow connection from your IP address. This you can configure in Azure Portal.